# setcookie (example from manual) not set

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

Why setcookie is not work?
I get data from database and try setcookie, but it is not set. I get example from php manual

```
$usrunic = $row['userunic'];
$usrfname=$row['first_name'];
$usrlname=$row['last_name'];
session_start();
$_SESSION['email']=$usremail;
$_SESSION['userid']=$usrunic;
$_SESSION['username']=$usrfname;
$_SESSION['userlname']=$usrlname;
if (!isset($_COOKIE[$usremail])){
setcookie($usremail,$usrunic,time()+3600);//1h
}
```

Comment: Is that really all code you have? Nothing else above this?

Comment: No. above this connection to dbase where i get $usrunic = $row['userunic'];
$usrfname=$row['first_name'];
$usrlname=$row['last_name'];

Comment: Does the session get set?

Comment: You know you can't have output above the setcookie? Also you know you have to reload the page to see that the cookie has been set if you read the cookie through php.?

Comment: maybe it's because of using a localhost? session_start() work only

Comment: I read cookie on other page which started with                                  <?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['email'])&&!isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
 header('Location: index.php');
}
 //+session_data
    $userid=$_SESSION['userid'];
    $useremail=$_SESSION['email'];
 $usrfname=$_SESSION['username'];
 $usrlname=$_SESSION['userlname'];
    //-session_data
if (!isset($_COOKIE[$useremail])){
 echo 'cookie is not set ';
}else{
 echo 'cookie already set';
}

Comment: 'cookie is not set' write

Comment: Add another argument like `setcookie($usremail,$usrunic,time()+3600, '/');`

Comment: so it works, thanks